# Tangent space of a cubic

Tags: differential-geometry

my excercise is to find the tangent space of
$$M=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 1 \}.$$
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I use the structure theorem of tangent space, after some calculation I have the tangent space $$T_P M = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert y,z \in \mathbb{R}, x = 0 \}.$$ with $P = (1,0,0).$

Answer (score 1):

This manifold is given as the level set of a graph; i.e, it is the points $F(x,y,z) = 0$ where $F(x,y,z) = x^3+y^3+z^3 - 1$. The tangent space at $p \in M$ is given by $\ker DF(p)$, where $DF$ is the derivative of $F$.

Comment: And the result is the $T_PM$ like what I did.